# Bitnami Multiple sites redirecting to One site

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, virtualhost, bitnami

I am very new to bitnami/apache/aws and have recently been assigned with figuring out why 3 of our sites are redirecting to one specific site. I have spent countless hours on this and i think i have narrowed it down to the app.conf files. Even when i try to access the /wp-admin or /administrator urls it take me to the other site. Here are two of the app.conf files. Let me know if anything looks out of place. Thanks in advance.

Main site all others are redirecting to

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/www.blueleafdef.com/htdocs
> ServerName blueleafdef.com
> ServerAlias www.blueleafdef.com
> ServerAlias blueleafdefr.uat.ignitedev.com
> ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.blueleafdef.com/log/error.log
> CustomLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.blueleafdef.com/log/access.log common
>
> <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/www.blueleafdef.com/htdocs">
> Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
> AllowOverride All
> Order allow,deny
> Allow from all
> </Directory> </VirtualHost>
> ```

One example of other site

> ```
>  <VirtualHost *>
> DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/htdocs
> ServerName www.fuelsnews.com:80
> ServerAlias www.fuelsnews.com
> ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/log/error.log
> CustomLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/log/access.log common
>
> <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/htdocs">
>     Options Indexes MultiViews
>     AllowOverride All
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
> </Directory> </VirtualHost>
>
>
> <VirtualHost *>
> DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/htdocs
> ServerName fuelsnews.com:80
> ServerAlias fuelsnews.com
> ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/log/error.log
> CustomLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/log/access.log common
>
> <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/htdocs">
>     Options Indexes MultiViews
>     AllowOverride All
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
> </Directory> </VirtualHost>
>
>
> <VirtualHost *>
> DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/htdocs
> ServerName fuelsnewsr.uat.ignitedev.com:80
> ServerAlias fuelsnewsr.uat.ignitedev.com
> ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/log/error.log
> CustomLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/log/access.log common
>
> <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/htdocs">
>     Options Indexes MultiViews
>     AllowOverride All
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
> </Directory> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below and restart the apache it will work.

```
    <VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/htdocs
ServerName www.fuelsnews.com
ServerAlias fuelsnews.com
ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/log/error.log
CustomLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/log/access.log common

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/htdocs">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory> </VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/htdocs
ServerName fuelsnewsr.uat.ignitedev.com
ServerAlias fuelsnewsr.uat.ignitedev.com
ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/log/error.log
CustomLog /opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/log/access.log common

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/www.fuelsnews.com/htdocs">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory> </VirtualHost>
```